# Написать функцию поиска подстроки в строке C++

Tags: c++, указатели, память, ссылки

Есть задание, которое звучит так:
"Напишите функцию char* findx (const char* s, const char* x), находящую первое вхождение C-строки x в  C-строку s. Не используйте никаких стандартных функций, не используйте индексирование, вместо него используйте оператор * разыменования."

```
#include "functions.h"

char* my_findx(const char* src,const char* x) {
    int length = 0, x_len = 0;

    while (*x++) x_len++;
    while (*src) {
        if (*src == *x) {
            const char* buf = src;
            const char* buf_x = x;
            while (*x) {
                if (*src == *x) {
                    ++length;
                    ++x;
                    ++src;
                } else break;
            }
            if (x_len == length) return const_cast<char*>(buf);
            else {
                src = buf;
                x = buf_x;
            }
        }
        ++src;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Функция main:

```
int main() {
    char* str = "Hello, Jack! What's up?";
    char* sub_str = "What's";

    cout << my_findx(str, sub_str);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В файле "functions.h" находится объявление функции my_findx.
Ошибка:[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрим на код...

```
while (*x++) x_len++;
```

Здесь по окончании работы `x` указывает на первый символ *после* строки, переданной как `x`. Далее вы продолжаете работать с этим указателем, как с подстрокой - т.е. за границами выделенной памяти, вообще говоря.

Дальше даже не смотрел...

Comment: Действительно, не заметил, что после использование строки не вернул указателю начальный адрес. strlen не использую, так как в условии сказано, что стандартные функции использовать запрещено. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Ну, если он решил ваши проблемы - отмечайте как принятый...

Comment: `Почему бы вам не написать x_len = strlen(x)?` — `Не используйте никаких стандартных функций`

Answer (score -2):

Вот вам пример решенного задания(этот код написал я):

```
#include <iostream>

char getitem(const char* s, int idx) {
  return *(s + idx);
}


int len(const char* s) {
  int i = 0;
  for(;(getitem(s, i) != '\0'); i++);
  return i;
}


int my_find(const char* src, const char* tmpl) {
  for(int i = 0; len(src) != i; i++) {
    for(int j = 0, k = i; len(tmpl) != j; j++, k++) {
      if (getitem(src, k) != getitem(tmpl, j)) {
        goto next_find;
      }
    }
    return i;
    next_find: {}
  }
  return -1;
}

int main() {
  char* str = "Hello, Jack! What's up?";
  char* sub_str = "What's";
  auto idx = my_find(str, sub_str);
  std::cout << "s[" << idx << "] ==  " << getitem(str, idx) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `+ (sizeof(char) * idx)` - ну это жесть какая-то. Арифметика указателей сама разберётся с `sizeof(...)`, уберите. К тому же, в вопросе нужно вернуть не индекс, а адрес. Плюс не оптимизировано - len вызывается на каждой итерации. Минус, извините

Comment: Можете кинуть цитату из вопроса где говориться  что нужно вернуть адрес?

Comment: " len вызывается на каждой итерации"  у меня VS 2017 на O2  выдает одинаковую скорость (то есть вариант с одним вычислением len по скорости равен варианту с множественными вычислениями len), из чего можно сделать вывод что оптимизатор выкидывает повторы. Так что проблем нет.

Comment: "Напишите функцию char* findx (const char* s, const char* x)" - в сигнатуре функции прописано. Хотя `const` не хватает. Не нужно надеяться на оптимизацию всё время, в этом примере могло просто повезти. В более сложной ситуации это может серьёзно замедлить программу, а приучаться к хорошему коду надо сразу